# learning steps for image recognition algorithm

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation, jpeg, image-recognition

I have decided to spend my personal time after office hours to learn the building blocks of how images jpeg type are parsed and represented in screen. My interest is on object recognition in an image.so I want to know where to start , I know there are math involved in this.so I needed step by step on what resources in Internet specifically to look at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Need a lot more information on what you want, but take a look at OpenCV

http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/

To see good examples.

Answer (score 4):

I'd get [Ritter's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=YBlSUIybptwC&lpg=PP1&ots=sPNHyBGOuG&dq=ritter%20image%20algebra&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) (warning: costly!) and give it serious studying.  If you just want to grab existing code and go play then perhaps you should look at libraries like OpenCV (see Lou's answer).

Answer (score 3):

The ultimate goal of most image processing is to extract information about some high-level and application-dependent objects from an image available in low-level (pixel) form. The objects may be of every day interest like in robotics, cosmic ray showers or particle tracks like in physics, chromosomes like in biology, houses, roads, or differently used agricultural surfaces like in aerial photography or synthetic-aperture radar, etc.

This task of pattern recognition is usually preceded by multiple steps of image restoration and enhancement, image segmentation, or feature extraction, steps which can be described in general terms. The final description in problem-dependent terms, and even more so the eventual image reconstruction, escapes such generality, and the literature of application areas has to be consulted.